# How do I configure which concrete class is bound in a Guice module depending on a @Named parameter?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'm reading configuration values from a properties file using Names.bindProperties().

I have an interface, let's call it Fruit, and I want to bind it either to Apple or Orange concrete classes depending on the value of one of these parameters in a properties file.

I was thinking something like this:

```
@Provides Fruit provideFruit(@Named("fruit-type") String fruitType) {
    switch (fruitType) {
       case "apple":
           return ???;
       case "orange":
           return ???;
    }
}
```

The question is how can I get an instance of Apple or Orange from within the provides method, such that it will be created by Guice?

I guess I could have Apple and Orange as parameters to the provides method, but that seems wasteful as they would be created regardless of which was used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[For any type `T`, you can inject `Provider<T>`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/Injector.html) even if you never explicitly bound a Provider for that type. Guice will inject a generic Provider instance that, when invoked, will request an instance from the Injector with the requested key. This will avoid creating an instance unless `get` is called on the correct Provider.

This is not unique to @Provides methods; you can inject a `T` or `Provider<T>` anywhere, and Guice will create a Provider or call Provider.get implicitly if necessary, including with `@Inject` fields, methods, or constructors.

```
@Provides Fruit provideFruit(
        @Named("fruit-type") String fruitType,
        Provider<Apple> appleProvider,
        Provider<Orange> orangeProvider) {
    switch (fruitType) {
       case "apple":
           return appleProvider.get();
       case "orange":
           return orangeProvider.get();
    }
}
```